# Error in DatabaseLink when trying to select from multiple tables

Tags: bugs, databaselink

I've noticed a rather inconvenient (assumed) bug when selecting data joined across multiple SQL tables.

Example:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
conn = OpenSQLConnection["publisher"]
```

Selecting from a single table works fine:

```
SQLSelect[conn, "ROYSCHED"] // Short
```

> `{{BS1011,0,5000,0.1},{BS1011,5001,50000,0.12},<<48>>,{PY2008,0,50000,0.1}}`

However, when joining across multiple tables, I run into issues:

```
SQLSelect[conn, {"TITLES","ROYSCHED"}, {{"TITLES","TITLE"},{"TITLES","TITLE_ID"},{"ROYSCHED","ROYALTY"}},
 SQLColumn[{"TITLES","TITLE_ID"}]==SQLColumn[{"ROYSCHED","TITLE_ID"}]]//Short[#, 15]&

>>If[DatabaseLink`SQL`Private`invalidTableNameQ[{TITLES,ROYSCHED}],Message[SQLTable::tablename,If[Head[{TITLES,ROYSCHED}]===SQLTable,First[{TITLES,ROYSCHED}],{TITLES,ROYSCHED}]],<<1>>]
```

It appears the private function `invalidTableNameQ` cannot handle lists. Also verified when you surround a single table name with brackets (ie `{"ROYSCHED"}`).

This seems like an obvious bug to me. I can fix it rather easy by navigating to `$DatabaseLinkDirectory/Kernel/SCUD.m` and manually add a `DownValue` for this function.

```
invalidTableNameQ[name_List]:=Or@@(invalidTableNameQ/@name)
```

Any ideas or other verifications before I slap on the bugs tag?

Comment: Does this happen if you write the join as plain SQL?

Comment: @R.M. Nope. If I write out the whole string and execute using `SQLExecute` it works fine.

Comment: @kale This issue is known and a fix is on the cards(either through paclet update or in next incremental version of Mathematica).